# Optimal way of fetching and appending large amount of images on slower connections

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mongodb

At the moment, I'm fetching 100-200 images via ajax-php-mongodb, ajax providing the initial call with parameters, server side php finding the appropriate mongo doc that has the array of all the grid fs file ids of the images, then php fetches the bytes of the images from gridfs, base64 encodes it, stores them all into a php array via loop and echos back the array string to ajax, which calls a function that appends the images.

The problem is on slower connections, especially older 3G conenctions, if the connection breaks halfway through, then the whole ajax request fails for all of the images.

Is there an established way where I could deal with this? I've thought of doing a continuous ajax request that confirms the data received every x/imageAmount times, but I was wondering if there is an established way of doing this, or maybe even a library.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have a specific answer for you, but loading 100-200 images is *always* going to be slow simply from the weight of data. There's not really a way to optimise this, apart from load less data. Try dropping the page size to 20-50 and improve the lazy loading if you can.

Comment: You might want to include more code and head over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: This should probably not be done using AJAX in the first place ... Base64 encoding produces roughly 4/3 the size of the original data - so you already managed to blow up the volume of data to send over the slow connection - not really clever IMHO. Plus, with your approach my browser has to wait until the complete response containing all 200 images has downloaded, before it can start to display a single image. You should rather write a script that returns the binary image data for one single image (no extra encoding), and then use that as `src` for `img` elements.

Comment: True, I created this system when I was still a beginner and just sticking with anything that worked, now I have to go back and improve it. But your revisions make absolute sense, thanks. Ajax is kind of a requirement though, as the parameters that decide the type of images you're going to get are chosen on the same page as they are displayed.

Comment: @CBroe " You should rather write a script that returns the binary image data for one single image (no extra encoding), and then use that as src for img elements." wouldn't that mean a separate frontend-serverside request for each image?

Comment: Yes. But wasn't I-don't-want-to-lose-everything-if-my-one-single-request-gets-aborted one of the problems you wanted to solve ...? Plus, with HTTP/2 that will not really matter much any more in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

The penalty for doing 100-200 requests is stablishing the TCP connection, so use keep alive to reuse connections.
With keep alive, http headers will be sent per request anyway, so, to compensate that do not do base64.

You can also cache images in memory to reduce latency and mongodb load (gridfs is not too eficient)